# Map-Making Point Connectivity Problem

Tags: path-connected

GOAL: Create the longest routes (in km) that follows the rules set below (for the game Need for Speed: Rivals)

RULES: No road (connection between two points) may be used twice. Single points CAN be used as many times as necessary, so long as the connection is not repeated.
The first route created must loop/have its start and end point be the same. The second route created does not have to, but can.

The example route reads as follows: ABDEMPNKHFCGEILOQPTRSJA= 84.6km. (this is the longest loop I could create)

A pair of reference maps and the data points spreadsheet are provided below.

[Game Map with all points and connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQcpv.jpg)

[Game Map with all points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDwDM.jpg)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cHPyE5GOZYZ6AapYLysdWECrMdHKfDUvRP3nxy6OlpI/edit?usp=sharing